# Riley Riddle #11 - 1%, with calcium

Tags: riddle

At first use the code for the medium of these words
Find contained a descriptor of successful tech nerds
Finally, you'll see a striking Sheffield loan
You might feel this once my solution is known.

Comment: There is affy that goes down and the stock affymax is going down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got it!

Is it

> Enriched?

First line is

> En for English which is the language

Second line is

> Rich because they are probably wealthy

Third line is

> Ched which is the first name of a football player from Sheffield on loan to League One club Fleetwood Town

Comment: rot13(Lhc! Tbbq wbo :). Ubcrshyyl svthevat bhg gur fbyhgvba yrnirf lbh srryvat raevpurq. Va grezf sbe gur gvgyr, 1% vf npghnyyl n qhny ersrerapr. Svefgyl, gur 1% vf yvgrenyyl raevpurq ol gurve rabezbhf jrnygu. Frpbaqyl, 1% vf n ersrerapr gb n xvaq bs zvyx, juvpu pna or raevpurq jvgu ahgevragf yvxr pnypvhz.)

Comment: rot13(Nyfb, Purq Rinaf vf zber guna whfg n sbbgonyy cynlre, ur'f n terng fgevxre va Yrnthr Bar (urapr jul ur vf n "fgevxvat" ybna).)

Comment: rot13(Gunaxf! :) Lrf, gur fgevxre ersrerapr jnf n xrl pyhr sbe zr. V qba'g xabj nalguvat nobhg fcbegf ohg vg fbhaqrq yvxr n cbfvgvba. Nyfb, zl cnegare jrag gb Havirefvgl ng Fbhgunzcgba. :)

Qvqa'g trg gur gvgyr gubhtu fb gunaxf! Jbhyq ybir gb qr-raevpu gur 1%, vs gung'f n jbeq.)